# Could not load SWT library when running a plugin on Eclipse (Mac M1)

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, apple-m1

I am trying to run one of my plug-ins in my eclipse work space but it gives the error log of

```
!SESSION 2022-10-09 22:05:38.541 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.24.0.I20220607-0700
java.version=16.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=aarch64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_SG
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.platform.ide
Command-line arguments:  -product org.eclipse.platform.ide -data /Users/me/eclipse-workspace/../runtime-EclipseXtext -dev file:/Users/me/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Launch Runtime Eclipse/dev.properties -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch aarch64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2022-10-09 22:05:46.651
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    /Users/me/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Launch Runtime Eclipse/org.eclipse.osgi/765/0/.cp/libswt-cocoa-4952r11.jnilib: dlopen(/Users/me/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Launch Runtime Eclipse/org.eclipse.osgi/765/0/.cp/libswt-cocoa-4952r11.jnilib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/me/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Launch Runtime Eclipse/org.eclipse.osgi/765/0/.cp/libswt-cocoa-4952r11.jnilib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/me/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Launch Runtime Eclipse/org.eclipse.osgi/765/0/.cp/libswt-cocoa-4952r11.jnilib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    no swt-cocoa in java.library.path: /Users/me/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
    no swt in java.library.path: /Users/me/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
    /Users/me/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-cocoa-4952r11.jnilib: dlopen(/Users/me/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-cocoa-4952r11.jnilib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/me/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-cocoa-4952r11.jnilib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/me/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-cocoa-4952r11.jnilib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    Can't load library: /Users/me/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-cocoa.jnilib
    Can't load library: /Users/me/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt.jnilib
    /Users/me/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-cocoa-4952r11.jnilib: dlopen(/Users/me/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-cocoa-4952r11.jnilib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/me/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-cocoa-4952r11.jnilib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/me/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-cocoa-4952r11.jnilib: mach-o, but wrong architecture

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1440)
```

My Mac has the M1 chip and is currently using the Big Sur Version 11.2.2. This is the java version that I am using:

```
java 17.0.4.1 2022-08-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.4.1+1-LTS-2)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.4.1+1-LTS-2, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The eclipse version I downloaded is Eclipse IDE for Java and DSL Developers AArch64.

Comment: What plugin is that

Comment: You've got some x86_64 mixed into that error output. Did you set your Target Platform's architecture correctly and use a corresponding JRE?

Comment: Please verify that JRE for macOS / AArch64 (ARM 64-bit) architecture is being used in the corresponding launch configuration.