# Issues running Java SWT app on macOS M1 machine

Tags: java, swt, apple-m1

I've been using the [*"Java SWT version"* of an app called PasswordSafe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpwsafe/) for many years on my Mac machines. It has been rock-solid. I've just bought a new iMac with the M1 processor because the "Fusion Drive" in my 2017 vintage iMac died. I installed Java, and the latest version of Java PasswordSafe on my new M1 iMac. Unfortunately, something is not working properly: The "top level" GUI looks normal, and it can open my PasswordSafe database file, but it presents a very garbled interface when I (for example) try to edit a password entry in the database.

I don't know much about Java - or SWT - never having written a single line of code in either. I've contacted the author of PasswordSafe, but he tells me that *Java  PasswordSafe* is no longer being maintained.

In brief summary, my question is, "In trying to repair this *broken-ness*, Where should I start? I realize that's a very lame question, but let me try to explain what I'm trying to learn:

- AIUI, Oracle no longer supports or provides a JRE or JDK that's compatible with the M1. I've read that [a third party does provide these tools](https://code2care.org/q/install-native-java-jdk-jre-on-apple-silicon-m1-mac), but apparently `Rosetta` allows the Oracle tools to run on the M1. In fact, during installation of Oracle's JRE/JDK, I saw a brief popup notification re `Rosetta`. My conclusion from this is that the Java software components (JVM or whatever) are operating, although sluggishly, and perhaps with other flaws due to `Rosetta` imperfections?
- The *assumption* that Java is more or less operational leads me to wonder about SWT. [There is another recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74008095/could-not-load-swt-library-when-running-a-plugin-on-eclipse-mac-m1) here on SO re issues with the SWT, but in my case, I get no displayed runtime errors - only a mangled interface. But then perhaps I'm not looking in the right place for those errors?
- I've done a bit of research on the status of SWT on M1, but [found no clues on their website](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/). I haven't found any clear answers on whether or not SWT runs on M1 or not.

So that's what I've got - a very ill-defined situation with no obvious way ahead, and no experience in SWT or Java to guide me.

Comment: *but it presents a very garbled interface when I (for example) try to edit a password entry in the database.* I'm surprised you didn't include a screenshot of that but I'm going to guess that there could be problems with the graphics interface. I think you're pushing too much against the flow here, but if you're determined to use this particular software (which afaics is pretty similar to other open password managers) I would suggest you try it in a virtual machine. Having said that though, it might need also to virtualize the graphics if my suspicion is correct and I'm not sure if you can.

Comment: @g00se: I considered a screenshot, but wondered if it would help explain the problem. I'll post one asap. WRT *pushing against the flow*: Perhaps you've never tried to migrate an encrypted password database with about 5K entries? :)

Comment: Oracle does provide a Java for the M1 (the aarch64 build), SWT also has an aarch64 build for Macs. The problem is that SWT is processor architecture specific so the program you have won't just run on the aarch64 Java it would have to be rebuilt with the aarch64 version of SWT. Older versions of SWT have problems on the current macOS so you may also be hitting that.

Comment: @greg-449: I must have missed that on Oracle's website - I'll double-check that. I seem to recall seeing aarch64 versions of SWT, but it's only now struck me that `aarch` might stand for "Apple Architecture"?? :)  Just so I'm clear on your comments, are you saying: *Re-building* the [existing sources](https://sourceforge.net/p/jpwsafe/code/) with current JDK & SWT **may** fix things?

Comment: aarch64 is the Arm 64 bit architecture that the Apple processors (and many others) use. Oracle builds are [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk19-mac) Current SWT builds are [here](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.25-202208311800/) (near the bottom). Just rebuilding wouldn't be enough, the build would have to be modified to build an aarch64 version - but it might then work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm now thinking it's got to be multi-user as not many people are going to have 5000 passwords ;)